# Which browser used in Cordova Apache windows?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, cordovawebview, cordova-windows

Just checked `window.navigator.userAgent` and got the following details.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; MSAppHost/3.0)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134
```

It is windows Edge 42. From where the browser is coming?

1. From the Visual Studio used (eg:- VS 2017)?
2. From the OS the app developed?
3. From the OS the app is running?
4. From Cordova main code (eg:- Cordova 8)?
5. From the windows cordova platform added. (eg:- platform windows 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova Windows projects are UWP JS projects. The "webview" (It's not really a webview in the classic sense, as the *whole* app is running in it, there is not other UI around the webview) used to run your Cordova web app is defined by that project. Depending on if you build this *for* Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, you will get different runtimes (probably IE11 for Win8.1, and Edge for Win10).

So:

- not relevant: Visual Studio, OS version developed on, Cordova CLI version, Cordova Platform version.
- relevant: OS build for and run on, Cordova Windows version.

Comment: I myself didn't verify the correctness of the answer. But accepting the answer for recognising his efforts.